# Asynctask: onCancelled() doesnt get called after cancel(true)

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am having trouble with the onCancelled() method from Androids AsyncTask.

In the asyncTask I am printing something on a Bluetooth pos Printer. Therefore i need to open a port and send the command via BT to the Device.

In the doInBackground() Method i have several control steps which can cancel the task, too, and  everything works as it should.
But when I try to open the port, and it's having trouble opening the port I let it try opening the port several times. When this all fails I cancel the Task. BUT this is the point where it does not work as it should (I guess), because it cancels the task, but doesnt call onCancelled().

Here is some Code. Tell me if you need more:

```
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            try{
                port = StarIOPort.getPort(printer.portName, printer.portSettings,
                        task.getProperties().getPortTime(), printer);
            } catch (StarIOPortException e){
                printer.printerServiceListener.onErrorOccured(
                        new PrintingError(task, Reason.PORT_OPEN_ERROR));
                try{Thread.sleep(task.getProperties().getSleepTime());
                }catch(InterruptedException ie){System.out.println("PrintTask: Thread slept...");}
            }
        }
        if(port == null && count == 0){
            critError = Reason.CONNECTION_FAILURE;
            critState = State.IDLE;
            cancel(true);
        }
        if(isCancelled()){
            cancel(true);
        }
```

I hope someone can help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Most probably you should `break;` from `doInBackground()` after `cancel(true);`

Comment: I can't `break;` it from that part of code. :/

Answer (score 0):

Do like This -

declare your asyncTask globally.

```
private YourAsyncTask mTask;

onCreate(){

    mTask = new YourAsyncTask().execute();
}
```

now kill like this in doInBackground() -

mTask.cancel(true);